# Compression/decompression using Huffman Coding Algorithm

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, tree, compression

I am writing a program that compresses and decompresses data using the *Huffman Coding algorithm.*

**About compression:** this program will export 2 files: header file (contains characters' frequency for re-constructing the Huffman Code Tree for decompressing data) and actual compressed data.

**About decompression:** After joining both files above, the program will decompress the data and write to file.

I am a beginner in C++ and would love to hear some feedback about my code style as well as my code design.

Thank you.

**hzip.hpp** (class for building Huffman Code Tree)

```
/*
* Author: Harry Nguyen
* Date: 23/05/2018
*/ 

#ifndef _HZIP_HPP
#define _HZIP_HPP

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <queue>

// Data type for a Huffman char
typedef unsigned short hchar_t; 

// Data type for frequency 
typedef unsigned int hfreq_t;

// Data type for frequency table
typedef std::map<hchar_t, hfreq_t> frmap_t; 

// Data type for huffman code map
typedef std::map<hchar_t, std::string> hmap_t; 

// Data type for a bit
typedef char bit_t;

const hchar_t PSEUDO_EOF = 256; // A virtual end of file 
const hchar_t NOT_A_CHAR = 257; // Write to internal nodes
const bit_t MAX_NUMBER_OF_BITS = 8; 

/* Convert string of bits ( "0" or "1") 
*  to real byte 
*  Return converted bytes in the form of strings
*/
std::string stobyte(std::string& sBits);

/*
* A Huffman node contains a character, its frequency
* and 2 children node
*/
struct NODE
{
    hchar_t _character;
    hfreq_t _freq;

    NODE* _lChild;
    NODE* _rChild;

    NODE(hchar_t character, hfreq_t freq):
        _character(character), _freq(freq),
        _lChild(nullptr), _rChild(nullptr) {}

    ~NODE() {
        delete _lChild;
        delete _rChild;
    }
};

// ADT for min heap implementation
struct Comparator
{
    bool operator()(NODE* lChild, NODE* rChild) 
    {
        return lChild->_freq > rChild->_freq;
    }
};

class HZip
{
public:
    HZip();

    /*
    * Build a frequency table from input string
    * and return a frequency map.
    */
    frmap_t buildFrequencyTable(const std::string& input);

    /* 
    * Build a Huffman tree from frequency table
    * and return the root.
    */
    NODE* buildEncodingTree(frmap_t freqTable);

    /*
    * Get encoded map from the root of encoded tree
    * and return encoded map.
    */
    hmap_t getEncodedMap(NODE* encodingTree);

    /*
    * Read characters from input string 
    * and write bytes to output.
    * -------------------------------------
    * Used for compression
    */
    void encodeData(std::string& input, const frmap_t freqMap, 
                    hmap_t encodedMap, std::vector<std::string>& output);

    /*
    * Construct frequency table from the header 
    * of the input string.
    * ------------------------------------------
    * Used for decompression
    */
    frmap_t headerProcessing(std::string& input);

    /*
    * Read bits by bits from the input string
    * and write character to the output.
    * ----------------------------------------
    * Used for decompression
    */
    void decodeData(std::string& input, NODE* encodingTree, std::string& output);

protected:
    /*
    * Build Huffman encoding map.
    * ----------------------------
    * Recursive approach.
    */
    void buildEncodingMap(NODE* encodingTree, std::string sCode);

protected:
    hmap_t p_encodedMap;

private:
    std::priority_queue<NODE*, std::vector<NODE*>, Comparator> m_minHeap;
};

#endif
```

**hzip.cpp**

```
#include "hzip.hpp"

/* Convert string of bits to bytes
*/
std::string stobyte(std::string& sBits)
{
    std::string sBytes;

    std::size_t numberOfBits = 0;
    bit_t bit = 0;

    /* Iterate through string of bits 
    * If there are not enough 8 bits (to construct 1 byte) 
    * when reaching the end of string bits then
    * 0 will be filled. That's the purpose of "+ numberOfBits"
    */
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < sBits.size() + numberOfBits; ++i) {

        // Convert character in form of binary to real bits.
        (sBits[i] == '0') ? (bit = 0) : (bit = 1);

        // Initialise byteChar once
        static char byteChar = 0;

        // then get 1 bit
        byteChar = (byteChar << 1) | bit;

        ++numberOfBits;

        // If reaching 8 bits (1 byte)
        if (numberOfBits == MAX_NUMBER_OF_BITS) {
            // then add that byte to the string
            sBytes += byteChar;

            // and reset byteChar and numberOfBits for the next iteration
            byteChar = 0;
            numberOfBits = 0;
        }
    }

    return sBytes;
}


HZip::HZip()
{}

frmap_t
HZip::buildFrequencyTable(const std::string& input)
{
    frmap_t freqTable;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
        ++freqTable[hchar_t(input[i])]; // cast input[i] from char to hchar_t 

    // push a PSEDO_EOF to frequency table with freq = 1
    freqTable[PSEUDO_EOF] = 1;

    return freqTable;
}

NODE* 
HZip::buildEncodingTree(frmap_t freqTable)
{
    // push each char and its frequency to min heap
    for (auto it = freqTable.begin(); it != freqTable.end(); ++it)
        m_minHeap.push(new NODE(it->first, it->second));

    // push until there is just 1 node left (root)
    while (m_minHeap.size() > 1) {
        // get least frequency node
        NODE* lChild = m_minHeap.top();
        m_minHeap.pop();

        // get next least frequency node
        NODE* rChild = m_minHeap.top();
        m_minHeap.pop();

        /*
        * Make a parent node with
        * key is a char or a NOT_A_CHAR which indicates an internal node
        * value is the sum of 2 least frequency
        */
        NODE* parent = new NODE(NOT_A_CHAR, lChild->_freq + rChild->_freq);

        // Link to its children
        parent->_lChild = lChild;
        parent->_rChild = rChild;

        m_minHeap.push(parent);
    }

    // Top of min heap is the root of built tree
    return m_minHeap.top();
}

/*
* Traverse binary tree recursively
* and push char and its huffman code to the map
*/
void 
HZip::buildEncodingMap(NODE* encodingTree, std::string sCode)
{
    if (!encodingTree) 
        return ;

    // If leaf node
    if (encodingTree->_character != NOT_A_CHAR) 
        p_encodedMap.insert(std::pair<hchar_t, std::string> (encodingTree->_character, sCode));

    HZip::buildEncodingMap(encodingTree->_lChild, sCode + "0");
    HZip::buildEncodingMap(encodingTree->_rChild, sCode + "1");
}

/*
* Get Huffman coding Map
*/
hmap_t
HZip::getEncodedMap(NODE* encodingTree)
{
    HZip::buildEncodingMap(encodingTree, "");
    delete encodingTree;
    return p_encodedMap;
}

void
HZip::encodeData(std::string& input, const frmap_t freqMap, 
                 hmap_t encodedMap, std::vector<std::string>& output)
{
    /*
    * Construct the header 
    * Format: {,<hchart>$<hfreq>...}
    */
    std::string header;
    header = "{";
    for (auto it = freqMap.begin(); it != freqMap.end(); ++it) 
        header += "," + std::to_string(it->first) + "$" + std::to_string(it->second);
    header += "}";

    /*
    * Reconstruct the document with string of '0' and '1'
    */
    std::string sBits;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
        sBits += encodedMap[hchar_t(input[i])];
    }
    // Put a PSEUDO_EOF at the end of the input string
    sBits += encodedMap[PSEUDO_EOF];

    // Vector output contains 2 parts: the header and actual compressed data
    output.push_back(header);
    output.push_back(stobyte(sBits));
}

frmap_t
HZip::headerProcessing(std::string& input)
{
    frmap_t freqTable;

    /* Get header */
    std::size_t endOfHeader = input.find_first_of("}");
    std::string header = input.substr(0, endOfHeader + 1);

    /* Positions for constructing key/value from header */
    std::size_t start = header.find_first_of("{,") + 2;
    std::size_t end = start;

    while (start < header.size()) {
        end = header.find_first_of("$", start);
        // get character from header
        std::string character = header.substr(start, end - start); 
        hchar_t hCharacter = std::stoi(character); // convert string to integer
        start = end + 1;


        end = header.find_first_of(",}", start);
        // get frequency from header
        std::string freq = header.substr(start, end - start);
        hfreq_t hFreq = std::stoi(freq); // convert char(freq) to integer
        start = end + 1;

        // Reconstruct freqTable
        freqTable.insert(std::pair<hchar_t, hfreq_t> (hCharacter, hFreq));
    }

    return freqTable;
}

void 
HZip::decodeData(std::string& input, NODE* rootOfEncodedTree, std::string& output)
{
    // initialise current node 
    NODE* curNode = rootOfEncodedTree;

    // flag for break 2 loops
    bool flagBreak = false;

    /* Get position right after the header */
    std::size_t endOfHeader = input.find_first_of("}");
    std::size_t pos = endOfHeader + 1;

    while (pos < input.size()) {
        /* Read 1 bit at a time from input */
        for (bit_t j = MAX_NUMBER_OF_BITS - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
            // Get bit
            bit_t bit = (input[pos] >> j) & 0x01;

            /* If bit = 0 then go to the left child
            * else go to the right child
            */
            (bit == 0) ? 
                (curNode = curNode->_lChild) : (curNode = curNode->_rChild);

            // Reach the end of input
            if (curNode->_character == PSEUDO_EOF) {
                // turn on flagBreak for breaking the while loop
                flagBreak = true;

                // break the for loop
                break;
            }

            // If reaching leaf node
            else if (curNode->_character != NOT_A_CHAR) {
                // print node's character and add to the output
                output += curNode->_character;

                // Scan from root again
                curNode = rootOfEncodedTree;
            }
        }

        // Used for break the outer loop (while loop)
        if (flagBreak)
            break;

        // next position of input string
        ++pos;
    }
}
```

**hfile.hpp** (Header file for file and string processing)

```
#ifndef _HFILE_HPP_
#define _HFILE_HPP_

#include "hzip.hpp"

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

const unsigned char HEADER = 0;
const unsigned char ACTUAL_COMPRESSED_DATA = 1;

/* Namespace for file extensions */
namespace h_extension {
    const std::string hzip = ".hzip";
    const std::string har = ".har";
}

/*
*  Namespace for path manipulation
*  ----------------------------------------
*  Can be used for constructing the path of 
*  compressed and decompressed file
*/
namespace hfile {
    std::string getFileName(const std::string& path_to_file);
    std::string getParentDicrectory(const std::string& path_to_file);

    /* Get the extension of file need to be compressed
    *  Example: raw file: test.txt -> .txt
    *  --------------------------------------------------
    *  Used for constructing the path to compressed file
    */
    std::string getSourceFileExtension(const std::string& path_to_file);

    /* Get the extension of original file 
    *  Example: compressed file: test.txt.har -> txt
    *  ---------------------------------------------------
    * Used for constructing the path to decompressed file
    */ 
    std::string getOriginalFileExtension(const std::string& path_to_file);

    std::string getSrarExtension(const std::string& path_to_file);
}

/* Compress inFile and split into 2 files: 
*          the header and actual compressed file.
*  ---------------------------------------------------
*  dest_file_path is the path to the directory you want to write 
*  your compressed file to, no need to include file name.
*/
void compress(const std::ifstream& inFile, 
              std::ofstream& outHeaderFile, std::ofstream& outDataFile, 
              const std::string& source_file_path, 
              const std::string& dest_file_path,  
              const std::string& extension);


/* Join 2 files inFile_1 and inFile_2 and write to outFile.
*  -----------------------------------------------------------------------
*  dest_file_path must include file name you want to create after joining
*/
void joinFile(const std::ifstream& inFile_1, const std::ifstream& inFile_2, 
              std::ofstream& outFile, 
              const std::string& source_file_path,
              const std::string& dest_file_path);


/* Decompress inFile and write to outFile 
*  -------------------------------------------------------------------
*  dest_file_path is the path to the directory you want to write 
*  your compressed file to, no need to include file name.
*/
void decompress(const std::ifstream& inFile, std::ofstream& outFile, 
                const std::string& source_file_path, 
                const std::string& dest_file_path);

#endif
```

**hfile.cpp**

```
#include "hfile.hpp"

std::string 
hfile::getFileName(const std::string& path_to_file)
{
    std::size_t start = 0;

    /* In case there is no parent directory at all */
    if (path_to_file.find_last_of("/") != std::string::npos) 
        start = path_to_file.find_last_of("/") + 1;
    else 
        start = 0;

    std::size_t end = path_to_file.find_first_of(".", start);

    std::string file_name = path_to_file.substr(start, end - start);

    return file_name;
}

std::string 
hfile::getParentDicrectory(const std::string& path_to_file) 
{
    std::size_t end = 0;

    /* In case there is no parent directory at all */
    if(path_to_file.find_last_of("/") != std::string::npos)
        end = path_to_file.find_last_of("/") + 1;
    else 
        end = 0;

    std::string parent_directory = path_to_file.substr(0, end);

    return parent_directory;
}

std::string
hfile::getSourceFileExtension(const std::string& path_to_file) 
{
    std::size_t start = path_to_file.find_last_of(".");
    std::size_t end = path_to_file.size();

    std::string source_file_extension = path_to_file.substr(start, end - start);

    return source_file_extension;
}

std::string 
hfile::getOriginalFileExtension(const std::string& path_to_file) 
{
    std::size_t endOfPath = 0;

    /* In case there is no parent directory at all */
    if (path_to_file.find_last_of("/") != std::string::npos) 
        endOfPath = path_to_file.find_last_of("/");
    else
        endOfPath = 0;

    // find the distance between 2 "." in the path
    // example: test.txt.har -> 4 (.txt)
    std::size_t start = path_to_file.find_first_of(".", endOfPath);

    // get next position of "." 
    std::size_t end = path_to_file.find_first_of(".", start + 1);

    std::string original_file_extension = path_to_file.substr(start, end - start);
    return original_file_extension;
}

std::string 
hfile::getSrarExtension(const std::string& path_to_file)
{
    std::size_t start = path_to_file.find_last_of(".");
    std::size_t end = path_to_file.size();

    std::string srarExtension = path_to_file.substr(start, end - start);

    return srarExtension;
}

void compress(const std::ifstream& inFile, 
              std::ofstream& outHeaderFile, std::ofstream& outDataFile, 
              const std::string& source_file_path, 
              const std::string& dest_file_path, 
              const std::string& extension) 
{
    /* Read whole string in inFile 
    *  and store to inDoc
    */
    std::stringstream buf;
    buf << inFile.rdbuf();
    std::string inDoc = buf.str();

    /* Read more on Huffman coding for more info */
    HZip haz;
    frmap_t freqMap = haz.buildFrequencyTable(inDoc);
    NODE* root = haz.buildEncodingTree(freqMap);
    hmap_t encodedMap = haz.getEncodedMap(root);

    // data vector contains header and actual compressed data
    std::vector<std::string> data;

    haz.encodeData(inDoc, freqMap, encodedMap, data);

    /* Construct the path of header file
    *  header_file_path = dest_dir_path + "h@"+ source_filename + 
    *                     source_file_extension + huffman_extension
    */
    std::string header_file_path = hfile::getParentDicrectory(dest_file_path) + "h@" +
                                   hfile::getFileName(source_file_path) + 
                                   hfile::getSourceFileExtension(source_file_path) +
                                   extension;

    /* Write to header file */
    outHeaderFile.open(header_file_path, std::ios::binary);
    outHeaderFile << data[HEADER];

    /* Construct the path of actual compressed data file
    *  similar to header_file_path, except for "d@" + filename instead of "h@"
    */
    std::string data_file_path = hfile::getParentDicrectory(dest_file_path) + "d@" +
                                 hfile::getFileName(source_file_path) + 
                                 hfile::getSourceFileExtension(source_file_path) +
                                 extension;

    /* Write to actual compressed file */
    outDataFile.open(data_file_path, std::ios::binary);
    outDataFile << data[ACTUAL_COMPRESSED_DATA];
}

void 
decompress(const std::ifstream& inFile, std::ofstream& outFile, 
           const std::string& source_file_path,
           const std::string& dest_file_path)
{
    /* Read whole string in inFile 
    *  and store to inDoc
    */
    std::stringstream buf;
    buf << inFile.rdbuf();
    std::string inDoc = buf.str();

    /* Read more on Huffman coding decompression for more info */
    HZip haz;
    frmap_t freqTable = haz.headerProcessing(inDoc);
    NODE* root = haz.buildEncodingTree(freqTable);

    std::string decompressedDoc;
    haz.decodeData(inDoc, root, decompressedDoc);

    // Free allocated root
    delete root;

    /* Construct the path of decompressed file
    *  decompressed_file_path = dest_dir_path + <filename> + source_originalfile_extension
    */
    std::string decompressed_file_path = hfile::getParentDicrectory(dest_file_path) + 
                                         hfile::getFileName(source_file_path) + 
                                         hfile::getOriginalFileExtension(source_file_path);

    /* Write to outFile */
    outFile.open(decompressed_file_path, std::ios::binary);
    outFile << decompressedDoc;
}

void 
joinFile(const std::ifstream& inFile_1, const std::ifstream& inFile_2, 
         std::ofstream& outFile, 
         const std::string& source_file_path,
         const std::string& dest_file_path)
{
    /* Read whole inFile_1 and store to string inDoc_1 */
    std::stringstream buf1;
    buf1 << inFile_1.rdbuf();
    std::string inDoc_1 = buf1.str();

    /* Read whole inFile_2 and store to string inDoc_2 */
    std::stringstream buf2;
    buf2 << inFile_2.rdbuf();
    std::string inDoc_2 = buf2.str();

    // Join 2 strings
    std::string outDoc = inDoc_1 + inDoc_2;

    // Get raw file name (still contains "h@" and "d@")
    std::string source_file_name = hfile::getFileName(source_file_path);

    /* Remove "h@" or "d@" for getting actual file name */
    std::size_t start = source_file_name.find_first_of("@") + 1;
    std::size_t end = source_file_name.size();
    std::string joined_file_name = source_file_name.substr(start, end - start);

    /* joined_file_path = dest_dir + source_file_name + 
    *                     original_source_file_extension + srar_extension 
    */
    std::string joined_file_path = hfile::getParentDicrectory(dest_file_path) + 
                                   joined_file_name + 
                                   hfile::getOriginalFileExtension(source_file_path) +
                                   hfile::getSrarExtension(source_file_path);

    /* Write joined string to dest_file_path */
    outFile.open(joined_file_path, std::ios::binary);
    outFile << outDoc;
}
```

Comment: It's great that you're learning about compression, but this is *not* encryption. It's very important that you don't mix them up.

Comment: @Reinderien Thank you! Because I divide the compressed files into 2 files, and I guess that the compressed file could not be decompressed if there is no header. So I thought it was kind of encryption.

Comment: It's better than transmitting something plaintext, but only slightly. This would still be vulnerable to attack. If you want to understand why, I suggest that you open that as a separate question on the SE security site.